# Stop simultaneous GET request in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my web app I am using a web api, for that I am calling the angular js custom function when key up event happen, but the problem is when i press keys the previous get request not cancels , means all GET requests works at same time. 
the code I've written is as follows

**Angular Js**

```
var req = {
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'url of api',
         headers: {

            "Key": "keyofapi",
            "Accept": "application/json"
         },
        }

        $http(req).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

          });
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-keyup="check();" ng-model="myModel" />
```

console image:: [Click Here](http://s6.postimg.org/bw2uuera9/svo.png)

Comment: If you are firing events at each key pressed then this is the expected result. $http returns a promise so it waits till the request is resolved. This creates a race condition in your case. You should add a delay mechanism. If your Angular version is 1.3+ then you may use ng-model-options="{debounce: 300}" with your input field.

Comment: oke, I'll check this and revert you  @Ertunç

Comment: @Ertunç can you give me example code ?